# place NavigationBar subview behind the NavigationBarItem and title

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, subview, layoutsubviews

I want to **add a view below everything** that's on the navigationBar. I need to add them as **subviews to my NavigationBar** so that they appear on any detail ViewController.

Here is what I tried so far inside my custom NavigationBar subclass (I call this method inside `layoutSubviews()`):

```
private var backgroundView = UIView()

backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 70)
backgroundView.backgroundColor = .blue
backgroundView.alpha = 0.7
self.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)
```

And this is what I get:

[image: navigationBar with subview]

The backgroundView **appears on top of the title and the NavigationBarItem**.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85541) on the apple developer forum, you can do this inside the NavigationBar class (which works!):

`self.subviews[0].insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)`